# change from ubuntu 12.10 to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, 12.10

actually I was updating from ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10 suddenly my machine got switched off then when i restarted the machine I am facing the following problems:
1. **Even after doing shutdown it is not getting completely off.**
2. **I cannot update anything with update manager it is showing "Check Internet Connection" where I have a 15mbps broadband.**
3. whenever I am trying to update using update manager it is telling me not all update are installed the when I am doing partial update it is showing a error message as follows:

**failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libxatracker1_9.0.3-0ubuntu0.1_i386.deb**

then when I am doing do-release-update it is showing no new releases. so I want to return back to ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Rather than asking a new question we would like to encourage you to add additional information in an [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/305158/edit) to your first question. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I would have to say there are errors between the different version files. There may be other possibilities, but I would say a reinstall of the preferred version. Hope you had backups. Good Luck